# How to save value from Add More dynamic append multiple select box value using for loop php?

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter-3, implode

I am using append multi select box with some input text box also. i want save all data into table using for loop one by  one. I m finished this but problem is i couldn't implode multi select box value inside of for loop. i want store each loop individual in table.It always save first record only in team(multiselectbox value) Please help me.

My View Screen[image]

**My controller :**

```
public function saveprogress()
{

    $project_id=$this->input->post('project_id');
    $prog_date=$this->input->post('date');
    $task=$this->input->post('task');
    $team = $this->input->post('team');
    $report=$this->input->post('report');

    $numFields = count($prog_date);
    $teamFields = count($team);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++) {
        // Pack the field up in an array for ease-of-use.
        $field = array(
           'prog_date' => $prog_date[$i],
           'task' => $task[$i],
           'team' => $team[$i],
           'report' => $report[$i],
           'project_id' => $project_id
        );
     $result=$this->db->insert('progress', $field);
    }
    }
```

**My table after save (i selected 2 employee but store one in team column) :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**In view add [ ] square brackets after input name hope useful..**

```
 <input type="text" name="date[]">
```